# Android UI elements in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm designing an AR andorid application with Vufoira and Unity.Then; I want to add components like side bars in the camera view(Vuforia Scenes). But since I'm new on unity i don't know how to achieve since UI elements in Unity are pretty tough for me.

I bought this component to design easier my App views and also has build-ed views which you can modify quickly.Even though, Adding side bars on the camera views seems to be hard.

[UI builder](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/29757)

Any advice,tutorials you can give me on programming android events for achieving side Bar effects  in Unity i'd be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to use Android or iOS UI element directly in an Unity game/project. Unity has his own GUI abstraction, so you don't have worry about the code for a button in Android, iOS or PC game.

GUI in Unity (since Unity 5) are basically images that simulates buttons, bars, menus, etc... so, you can create beautiful ui if you have nice design skills.

If you wanna use Android style gui elements you must create every image that represent that component and you must create the code to achieve the behavior desired (so, this could be hard to complex android gui component like tabLayout o NavigationDrawer).

I found a project from a person who wants use iOS gui elements in unity, so he created the images and code for each component, still in beta but works nice for me:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-ios-for-unity-ui-ios-user-interface-design-for-unity.282399/

Comment: Hell you don't even need *good* design skills to make a png that makes for great UI when nine-sliced. Look at Minecraft's buttons and other GUI. Look at that clean, minimalist style. Its easy to make something similar and looks *really nice* when nine-sliced in Unity's UI framework.

Comment: You actually should be able to call for native UI via plugin in native code. It just does not make things easy as you'd have to build to test.

Comment: Wrong. It is possible to create a native overlay.

Comment: @Matt you want to share something helpful rather than a useless comment?

Comment: @ncrypticus Fair point; I had intended to come back with an answer showing how but never found the time. The short of it is that if you export a Unity project and open it in Android Studio you will see that the Unity game is simply an Activity like any other. So you can either [extend `UnityPlayerActivity`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190317195917/https://gravityjack.com/news/native-ui-overlay-for-unity-mobile-tutorials-part-2-android/) if you just want a native overlay, or you can write AAR plugins and import to Unity for more fine-grained control. I will try to remember to come back to this